# How to add a subtitle to a CSS website header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a subtitle below a website title, but am having difficulty. Trying to teach myself CSS so not that familiar yet, following a tutorial on YouTube but they do not include a subtitle.

This is what the page currently looks like:
[image: 1]

And how I want it to look:
[image: 2]

Can someone help with what I would need to do to get that with the following code?

I have tried adding a subtitle with h2, and creating it in the CSS but I think due to the way the nav is set up it is causing it to shift up like the navigation instead of below.

Thank you so much!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  color: #34325b;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding:
}

.nav-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34325b;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1 class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">TITLE</h1>

    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Just add a [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) below that title?

Comment: Anything I try to add below the title gets shifted up to the navigation. As I said in my post, I think it is due to the way the nav is set up in the CSS but I am not familiar enough to know how to fix it so that doesn't happen. When I try to move h1/h2 outside of the nav, the formatting breaks all together. I know it is probably an easy solution, I am just not seeing it as I am still learning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some divs to divide your title components into seperate elements within the `logo` element and use `display: flex;` and `align-items: flex-end`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.title {
  font-size: 48px;
}
.subtitle {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  color: #34325b;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding:
}

.nav-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34325b;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1 class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg"><div class="title"><div class="main_title">TITLE</div><div class="subtitle">MY SUBTITLE</div></div></h1>

    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Why don't u use a div to group h1 and img together instead of pumping everything into H1?

Comment: **down-voted for following reason**: `<h1>` is an `inline-element` and a `div` a `block-level-element`. As you know yourself, a `block-level-element` is not allowed to be a child of an `inline-element`. As such you're recommending an invalid HTML markup.

Comment: Instead of using an h1, you can use a div element. the output is the same because the font-size is overridden in the stylesheet.

Comment: @tacoshy `h1` definitely is *not*  an inline-element

Comment: right but still invalid to next it into an element where flow-content is expected.

Comment: @tacoshy so your argumentation for the downvote (i.e. in your previous comment) is kind of invalid, isn't it?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Because the OP had it that way in their code. As Matt Kent wrote, I simply took their code and *added* what was necessary to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div and change its display property to inline-block

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
}

#subtitle {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  color: #34325b;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding:
}

.nav-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34325b;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#title-subtitle-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">
      <div id='title-subtitle-container'>
        <div id='title'>TITLE</div>
        <div id='subtitle'>Subtitle</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #34325b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.subtitle {
  color: aqua;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  color: #34325b;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding:
}

.nav-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34325b;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
      <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">
    <div class="logo-title">
    <h1 class="logo">TITLE</h1>
    <span class="subtitle">SUBTITLE HERE</span>
    </div>
</div>

    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```